# How is vehicle respawn time calculated?

Tags: battlefield-1

I was wondering if anyone knew anything about the formula for vehicle respawn time is calculated.  For example, the vehicle respawn time could be as simple as 2 minutes after the last vehicle of the same type was destroyed.  Or it could be much more complicated, taking into account how long the last tank stayed alive or whether a certain amount of total time has passed since the start of the map.  For all I know vehicle respawn times are set with different values for each map.

Is there any data or information how vehicle respawn times are calculated?

Comment: Never when you are on the spawn screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this thread,](https://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_one/comments/58p1jj/what_is_the_respawn_time_on_tanksplanes/) where somebody sat down and timed vehicle respawns on an empty server, **planes** have a default respawn time of **1 minute 30 seconds**, and **tanks** a default respawn time of **2 minutes**.

However, these times can admittedly change based on a few factors. For example, the server itself has a vehicle respawn setting, which while set at 100% will conform to the times above, when adjusted may result in faster spawning vehicles.

Game mode can also have a perceived effect on vehicle spawn time. For example, in conquest, when having 2/3 points captured, there will usually be more tanks available to your team (obviously depending on the map), meaning that while it may appear that tanks are spawning faster, in fact there may just be more of them in play.

For what its worth my own timing on servers also anecdotally compare to the times measured above, though I was not intentionally timing it as the person in the above thread.

Comment: I have no data to back this up, but I believe the game "balancer" plays a part in vehicle respawns. As in, the losing team will get faster spawns to help them out. All gut feeling though.

Answer (score 0):

In the basic form it is just a X seconds after the same type of vehicle is destroyed it spawns again. This might be different for the bigger vehicles.